# What would be a stable way to hold lithium hydride powder?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, chemical-engineering

I currently have 100 grams of lithium hydride powder that needs to be held in a solid form. Initially, I was considering using cement, however, the moisture require converts the lithium hydride to lithium hydroxide. What would another moisture-free agent be that I could use for this task?

If it helps, the lithium hydride and the solidifying agent are to be used for neutron moderation.

Comment: How strong does the solid have to be, and what elements would be compatible, in terms of neutron cross-section?Paraffin wax has just H and C, but is not very strong. Seal it in polyethylene or polypropylene?

Comment: From what I remember, molten $\ce{LiH}$ is just poured under inert atmosphere into a container of the appropriate form, which is sealed later (or used in bulk – in aerospace industry). But it seems like you need some sort of a homogeneous solid matrix to keep $\ce{LiH}$ intact under ambient conditions, is it true?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

If the LiH needs to be exposed to ambient conditions, it should be enclosed is a moisture-impermeable container, e.g., a glass ampoule which is closed off. Glass can be blown quite thin - but then you need to be quite careful. As DrMoishe suggested, PE or PP would be good, but I'm thinking of it as a closed tube, not as a binder.